# GNU make kind-of-double colon

Tags: c++, makefile, gnu

I've got a little problem understanding following gmake syntax:

```
OBJ = foo.o bar.o

$(OBJ): %.o: %.cpp
    $(CC) -c -MMD -MP $(INCLUDES) $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@
    @sed (...create empty targets in file...)
```

I'm not sure what $(...): %.o: %.cpp does!?

I think it might translate the "%.o: %.cpp" in correct %.cpp dependencies - does it? Google is not much of a help here - it finds just the usual double colon (target::) which is something different!

Any advice? Thanks!

Comment: This is _widely_ documented on the internet. What research did you perform?

Comment: probably the wrong - not knowing it's called "static pattern rule"

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: It's difficult to search Google for a syntax pattern.  Really, the only way to do this (from first principles) is to trawl the documentation until you spot the pattern.

Comment: Haha...with the right name...it's even in my Mecklenburg book...I just didn't find it...sorry for bothering you!

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: Indeed. And that should have been performed before resorting to asking for free help.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: mhm...I spent the last week reading make documentation (O'reilly book, examples, more complex files...) to get a deeper understanding of how stuff works and stubled over this question...at some point it *should* be allowed to just ask a question - although I understand how little time you've got answering stupid stuff like this...it helps A LOT!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a [**static pattern rule**](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Static-Pattern).

`$(OBJ)` is a list of targets.  The `%.o : %.cpp` means "for each target in the list that matches `%.o`, it is dependent on `%.cpp`" (where the `%` is substituted accordingly).