# Error: "Mixed implicit and static pattern rules" in my Makefile

Tags: c++, windows, c++11, makefile

I had a working `Makefile` for small C++ applications that just had a couple of source code files inside a single folder that was also the output folder. Now I am trying to separate source and object files and ran into a problem. This is how my makefile looks right now, I'll go into detail where the problem occurs below.

```
CC = gcc
CXX = g++
RM = del

TARGET = plox.exe

CFLAGS = -Wall -ggdb -O3 $(INCLUDE)
CXXFLAGS = -std=c++11 -Wall -ggdb -O3 $(INCLUDE)
LDFLAGS = $(LIB) -lglfw3 -lopengl32 -lglu32 -lgdi32

INCLUDE = -I$(GLFW_INC) -I$(GLAD_INC)
LIB = -L$(GLFW_LIB)

SRC_DIR = src
BUILD_DIR = build

GLFW_DIR = d:/external/glfw-3.1
GLFW_INC = $(GLFW)/include
GLFW_LIB = $(GLFW)/lib64

GLAD = d:/external/glad-c
GLAD_INC = $(GLAD)/include

CXX_SOURCES = $(SRC_DIR)/%.cpp
CXX_OBJS = $(addprefix $(BUILD_DIR)/, $(CXX_SOURCES:.cpp=.o))
OBJS = $(CXX_OBJS) $(BUILD_DIR)/glad.o

all: $(TARGET)

$(TARGET): $(OBJS)
    $(CXX) -o $@ $^ $(LDFLAGS)

$(CXX_OBJS): %.o: $(SRC_DIR)%.cpp
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<

$(BUILD_DIR)/glad.o: src/glad.c
    $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) -c -o $(BUILD_DIR)/glad.o $(SRC_DIR)/glad.c

.PHONY: clean

clean:
    $(RM) $(TARGET) $(OBJS)
```

The problem is in the line:

```
$(CXX_OBJS): %.o: $(SRC_DIR)/%.cpp
```

Before my changes, it looked like this:

```
$(CXX_OBJS): %.o: %.cpp
```

A friend helped gave me a template and I never really knew what that line really does. In [another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8801539/gnu-make-kind-of-double-colon) I learned that this is a *static pattern rule* so I guess this is where I made the mistake. But writing it down just now, I think the error could be earlier already. I might have made a mistake when defining `$(CXX_OBJS)`. Could it be that the objects in that list are of the form `build/src/test.o` instead of `build/test.o`?

But how can I fix the `addprefix` line to produce the correct output? And where does the error in the title come from; where am I mixing those? I thought it could be about the `$(SRC_DIR)` in the static pattern rule because I probably misunderstood how it worked, but omitting it doesn't make the error go away. Moreover (assuming `CXX_OBJS` is working correctly later), if the static pattern rule checks every file in the list `$(CXX_OBJS)` for a match with `%.o`, and then has a dependency on the same file with ending `.cpp`, then that is also not correct because of the `build` folder prefix.

All in all, I'm very confused about how to handle the folder prefixes correctly and any advice is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Why do you need to separate object and source file?

Comment: @Steephen Hum, actually that's a good question. I was thinking about a 'good' project structure and perhaps went too far with separating stuff. But nevertheless I can learn something from this I think :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a static pattern rule, the words in the first section (the targets) have to be real files.  None of them can contain patterns (`%`).  You have:

```
CXX_SOURCES = $(SRC_DIR)/%.cpp
CXX_OBJS = $(addprefix $(BUILD_DIR)/, $(CXX_SOURCES:.cpp=.o))
$(CXX_OBJS): %.o: $(SRC_DIR)%.cpp
```

So `CXX_OBJS` is `$(BUILD_DIR)/$(SRC_DIR)/%.o`, which contains a pattern, so this is illegal.

I don't really know what you're trying to do with `CXX_SOURCES`.  Maybe you wanted:

```
CXX_SOURCES := $(wildcard $(SRC_DIR)/*.cpp)
```

instead?

Comment: I had to look up `wildcard` and indeed, I interpreted what `%` incorrectly and `wildcard` is what I want there. Is it correct that `CXX_SOURCES` now only has the files without the `$(SRC_DIR)` prefix? Because otherwise I'd think that it'd still be present in `CXX_OBJS`. After the `wildcard` change it now crashes in the line below `$(TARGET): $(OBJS)` with `mingw32-make: *** [plox.exe] Error 1`.

Comment: Maybe if you gave an explicit example of real file pathnames that you want to compile and what you want the output to be, it would be easier to understand what you're trying to do.  As for the message, that's not the error.  That's just make telling you something failed.  You have to look before that message and find the _first_ error message: that's the interesting one, not the last error message.

Comment: It was a silly error due to me renaming variables of an older makefile. See my answer for the details and thank you, it works now! :)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to [MadScientist's correct answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28786500/4298200), there was another error in my `Makefile` introduced by renaming variables: `mingw32-make` couldn't find the `-lglfw3` part because I used `$(GLFW)` in the definition of `GLFW_INC` and `GLFW_LIB`, but didn't define it. I wanted to have `$(GLFW_DIR)` instead.